# Blender Cycles black areas on transparent material (Principled Shader)

Tags: materials, node-editor, transparency

I am trying create a transparent plastic material. I am not sure why I am getting black areas on the transparent material...

[image]

What should I do to fix this and/or what might be some good resources to learn about what causes this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to raise the number of light bounces. This happens because the light paths need to bounce even more times until they finally hit some light source. With low number of allowed bounces, the rays get terminated permaturely.